# Refactoring with monads

Tags: scala

i'm new in Scala.

How can i refactor next code using monads or functors?

I guess, than print, append, map and fold must be refactored,
because they use the same functions: parse and iter.
But instances of parse and iter are different in each use

```
sealed trait List2[+A]
case object Null extends List2[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List2[A]) extends List2[A]

sealed trait Tree extends Ordered[Tree] {
    def compare(other: Tree): Int = this match {
        case Leaf(name: String, weight: Int) => weight.compareTo(other match {
            case Leaf(name: String, weight: Int) => weight 
            case Branch(name, childs) => (0)
        }) 
        case Branch(name, childs) => (0).compareTo((0))
    }
}
case class Leaf(name: String, weight: Int) extends Tree with Ordered[Tree]
case class Branch(name: String, childs: List2[Tree]) extends Tree with Ordered[Tree]

def print(t: Tree) = {

    def parse(t: Tree, spb: String): Unit = t match {
        case Leaf(name, weight) => println(spb + name) 
        case Branch(name, childs) =>
            println(spb + name)
            iter(childs, spb + "    ")
    }

    def iter(l: List2[Tree], spb: String): Unit = l match {
        case Null => 
        case Cons(head, tail) => 
            parse(head, spb)
            iter(tail, spb)
    }
    parse(t, "")
}

type addingTree = (String, String, Int)

def append(t: Tree, aT: addingTree): Tree = {

    def parse(t: Tree, aT: addingTree): Tree = t match {
        case Leaf(name, weight) => 
            if(name == aT._1) Branch(name,  Cons(Leaf(aT._2, aT._3), Null)) 
            else Leaf(name, weight)
        case Branch(name, childs) => Branch(name, iter(childs, name, aT))
    }

    def iter(l: List2[Tree], name: String, aT: addingTree): List2[Tree] = l match {
        case Null => 
            if(name == aT._1) Cons(Leaf(aT._2, aT._3), Null) 
            else Null
        case Cons(head, tail) => 
            Cons(parse(head, aT), iter(tail, name, aT))
    }
    parse(t: Tree, aT: addingTree)
}

def map(t: Tree)(f: Leaf => Leaf): Tree = {

    def parse(t: Tree)(f: Leaf => Leaf): Tree = t match {
        case Leaf(name, weight) => f(Leaf(name, weight))
        case Branch(name, childs) => Branch(name, iter(childs)(f))
    }

    def iter(l: List2[Tree])(f: Leaf => Leaf): List2[Tree] = l match {
        case Null => Null
        case Cons(head, tail) => Cons(parse(head)(f), iter(tail)(f))
    }
    parse(t)(f)
}

def fold[R](t: Tree)(f: (R, Tree) => R)(r: R): R = {

    def parse[R](t: Tree)(f: (R, Tree) => R)(r: R): R = t match {
        case Leaf(name, weight) => f(r, Leaf(name, weight))
        case Branch(name, childs) => iter(childs)(f)(f(r, Branch(name, childs)))
    }

    def iter[R](l: List2[Tree])(f: (R, Tree) => R)(r: R): R = l match {
        case Null => r
        case Cons(head, tail) => iter(tail)(f)(parse(head)(f)(r))
    }
    parse(t)(f)(r)
}
```

Thank you